# Laravel configuration of "database.php" file not works

Tags: laravel

i want to connect to database using database.php file, but it's not works.
I do not have the .env file.
I have to configure something more, beyond the file database.php

file database.php:

```
<?php
return [

 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

 'connections' => [

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'my_database'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'mydatabase'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,            
    ],
   ]
 ]
```

Comment: Just to be sure, does your file have the opening `<?php` ?

Comment: I checked and yes, is set

Comment: You may want to update your sample code, just so it's 100% clear.  Also, it is helpful when posting a question to include the exact error message, what you did to trigger it, and (often) what you expected to happen instead. 
Have you tried adding an `.env` file with some viable values?

Comment: -Error: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
-I can't use .env file in this situation

Comment: I would put that error in your question, for clarity.

Have you tried connecting to the MySQL database using the credentials (either the defaults, or the ones in your `.env`)?  E.g. `mysql -h localhost -umydatabase -p my_database` ?  I.e. are you sure you can connect to your db even without Laravel?

Comment: Yes,i can connect to DB without laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of you database connection values are set to take from env file. Since you are not using env, you have to set them in the `database.php` file manually.

```
return [

 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

 'connections' => [

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', 'Enter your db url here'), <--
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'Your db name'), <--
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'Db user name'), <--
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'Db password'), <--
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,            
    ],
   ]
 ]
```

Note: You might need to change these settings again for deployment. And you have `serve` it after changing the file.